# Voip or voice call record - Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to develop a xamarin.forms app which have the functionality to make call and record it.Why I am writing this question is I want some clarifications regarding this.I cant find a proper solution on web.

**1** The app workflow will be like this. When user tap on the number on my app it will open the dialer (in Android and iOS). User will complete the call and return back to app.The app will get the call record and store it.

Is this scenario possible with Xamarin.forms? If possible, any links will be appreciated.

**2.** Suppose the above scenaerio is not possible, then what will be the best approach? I heard about Twilio voip call sdk for xamarin. Is Twilio really support voip call for xamarin? I found these links, but it seems outdated.
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/11/twilio-client-for-xamarin-part-3-android.html
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/10/twilio-client-for-xamarin-part-2-ios.html Is there any other voip sdk available which will fullfil my requirement.Any help is appreciated. Because I have been stuck on this for days.

**EDIT** If I implement Twilio calling in web and calling it as a webview in mobile.Can I make work above scenario?

Comment: You can have a try with PortsIP . (https://www.portsip.com/download-portsip-voip-sdk/)  Or try with trial VoIP SIP SDK for Xamarin .(https://voipsipsdk.com/products/voip-sip-sdk-for-xamarin/download) Maybe they are not free.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks for commenting.will these will support to call from app to a normal number?

Comment: Eh, maybe this will not ,it is based on intent.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Twilio providing support for android and ios.Is it possible to integrate it with xamarin using xamarin bindings?

Comment: Twilio also be based on intent to communicate. It will be the same with PortsIP .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Bro sorry for bothering. If I Implement twilio on web and call it as a webview will it work?

Comment: Yeah , it will work.